# How to prevent perfplot (matplotlib) graph labels from being truncated?

Tags: python, matplotlib, perfplot

I'm working with the [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) library (which you can pip-install) which benchmarks functions and plots their performance.

**When observing the plotted graphs, the labels are truncated. How can I prevent this?**

Here's a simple MCVE:

```
import perfplot 
from itertools import chain

perfplot.__version__
# '0.8.8'

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: [[1] * 100] * n,
    kernels=[
        lambda L: sum(L, []),
        lambda L: list(chain.from_iterable(L))
    ],
    labels=['list_concat_sum', 'list_concat_chain'],
    n_range=range(1, 500, 100),
    xlabel='# lists',
    logy=True,
    logx=True)
```

This produces:

[image]

You'll notice the graph labels are truncated. Is there a way to prevent this, or change the graph to output a Legend?

Comment: In Colaboratory (perfplot-0.8.8), the labels were displayed normally without being broken.

Comment: @r-beginners huh, I'm running this in a terminal, not a notebook, so I see a different result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perfplot` seems to use matplotlib for the display. According to the github site, you can separate calculation and plotting, giving you the possibility to inject an autoformat (basically `plt.tight_layout()`) with [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) for this graph.

You can add the following before your script:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
```

Sample output:
[image]

Possible interactions with other graphs, though, when using this approach.